# O que este código faz? Necessito de uma descrição do seu funcionamento

Tags: php, array

```
$links=array("Apache Server" =>"www.apague,org", "Apress" =>"www.appress.org", "PHP" =>"www.php.net");
echo "Links ";
$cnt=0;
foreach($links as $key => $value) {
   echo $value .' -$cnt <br/>';
   $cnt++;
}
```

Necessito saber que o código faz o código indicado, e se possível uma descrição passo a passo do seu funcionamento.

Comment: Seria interessante voce pesquisar um pouco para melhorar a pergunta, isso é um loop de um array simples

Comment: É criado um array e depois cada valor dele é impresso na tela(foreach), `$cnt` exibe o número do elemento ...

Comment: Nada mais que um simples loop de array, veja mais informações no aqui http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque a qualidade é ruim e levará uma resposta onde teríamos que fazer longas explicações, para que o usuário entenda, já que o mesmo demonstra não saber nem mesmo com qual código está lidando.

Comment: `SO-PT é um site de perguntas e respostas para programadores profissionais e entusiastas[...]`, acho que *entusiastas* qualifica bem o *AP*. **-6** em 12 minutos é meio precipitado, sejamos flexíveis. Desculpem-me quem deu *down*, [IMHO].

Comment: Sei que a a qualidade da pergunta não é a melhor,  e é extremamente amadora, mas estou a começar com php e fiquei com algumas dúvidas em qual seria o resultado desse código. Na verdade, já estava à espera que fosse o conteúdo do array, mas ainda assim tinha algumas dúvidas e queria confirmar. Julgo que este fórum possa ser utilizado também para isso.

Obrigado pelas respostas.
Cumprimentos a todos.

Comment: Qual era a dúvida especifica? aproveite e leia [O Stack Overflow em Português é um fórum?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/91)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O vetor `$links` recebe 3 posições, cada uma com um endereço de site.
A variável `$cnt` é apenas um ponteiro.

O `foreach`, é uma função de laço, que faz (para cada posição no vetor `$links`) a impressão de `$value` (que contém, respectivamente em cada iteração, o respectivo conteúdo, neste caso um site).

E o trecho `'-$cnt < br />'` deveria estar entre aspas duplas (**"**), para ser impresso corretamente.

Corrigi algumas coisas no código, veja:

```
$links = array("Apache Server" => "www.apache.org", "Apress" => "www.appress.org", "PHP" => "www.php.net");

echo "Links: <br>";
$cnt = 0;
foreach ($links as $key => $value) {
    echo $value . " -$cnt <br/>";
    $cnt++;
}
```

Assim o Resultado fica:

> Links:
>   www.apache.org -0 
>  www.appress.org -1 
>  www.php.net
>   -2

---

Eu faria esta exibição assim:

```
$links = array("Apache Server" => "www.apache.org", 
                   "Apress" => "www.appress.org", 
                   "PHP" => "www.php.net");

$cnt = 0;
foreach ($links as $key => $value) {
    echo "Link[" . $cnt++ . "] " . $key . ' = ' . $value . " <br/>";
}
```

Pois as informações ficariam com maior intuitividade e didática:

> Link[0] Apache Server = www.apache.org 
>  Link[1] Apress =
>   www.appress.org 
>  Link[2] PHP = www.php.net

---

Espero ter ajudado. Abraços.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta. Foi muito útil. Cumprimentos!

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o seu problema esteja em `foreach($links as $key => $value) {`

Irei organizar o código:

```
$links = array(
      "Apache Server" => "www.apache.org", 
             "Apress" => "www.appress.org", 
                "PHP" => "www.php.net"
);

$cnt = 0;

foreach($links as $key => $value) {
   echo $value .' -$cnt <br/>';
   $cnt++;
}
```

Repare que existe uma semelhança entre:

```
$key => $value
```

Com este trecho da `array()`:

```
"Apache Server" => "www.apacue.org"
```

Acho que somente pelo `=>` conseguiria identificar quais são os valores, nesse caso, do `$key` e do `$value`.

Se pensou:

```
$key = "Apache Server"
$value = "www.apache.org"
```

Está correto, agora somente imagine o mesmo processado para todos os três elementos existentes.

**Mas, atenção!**

Nem sempre é `$alguma => $coisa`!

Você também pode utilizar:

```
<?

 foreach($links as $value) {
       echo $value .' -$cnt <br/>';
       $cnt++;
 }

?>
```

Sempre que houver somente UMA variavel, como `$value` (mas poderia ser qualquer nome) irá retornar apenas o resultado!

Isso é, irá somente conter: "www.apache.org", "www.appress.org", ou seja, tudo que estiver depois do `=>`, inclusive isso seria suficiente nesse caso.

Mas também tem um problema!

No caso o `$cnt` está entre `'`, isso faz com que o PHP não exiba o que a variavel contem.

Imagine isto:

```
<?php

$nome = 'Inkeliz';

echo '$nome';
// Irá exibir: $nome

echo $nome;
// Irá exibir: Inkeliz

echo "$nome";
// Irá exibir: Inkeliz

?>
```

Pela razão do `$cnt` estar entre `'` não é exibido o número dele, para isso basta alterar para:

```
  echo $value .' -'.$cnt.' <br/>';
// Equivalente ao Segundo método mostrado.
```

Uma outra possibilidade é:

```
  echo $value ." -$cnt <br/>";
// Equivalente ao terceiro método mostrado.
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Inkeliz, agradeço o tempo disponibilizado para me ajudar. Cumprimentos